# Azure private link to AKS with private endpoint to another AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-load-balancer, azure-private-link

I have a situation where my AKS cluster is already in place, two AKS clusters are there & they are internally available within their security zones only. I don't want to go via internet to access the internal resources within the cluster from another cluster.

I was exploring private link service & endpoint, any suggestions?

Both clusters are in different VNets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved this by creating private link service on load balancer where my internal ingress (private subnet) is connected in destination cluster. This will require resource ID & load balancer details.

Then created a private endpoint to the private link service in my source cluster that will require subnetId, Resource Group.

The IP created via private link endpoint can be used to communicate to internal LB & also created a DNS entry for it to be used as host in ingress object.

Answer (score 1):

You can host your private AKS clusters in a VNET and integrate your AKS clusters with private endpoint

Then you can communicate between your AKS clusters with private endpoints

If your AKS clusters are placed in different VNETs, you can do VNET peering between these VNETs

Then you would be able to communicate between your AKS clusters using the private endpoints